# Send data from local storage to online database mysql (Nodejs)

Tags: mysql, node.js, ajax, handlebars.js

I have data in my local storage, what is best way to send data to my online MySQL database with web service? My backend is Nodejs.

Thanks

Comment: Should be fairly straight forward. What have you tried to do. Is that data that gets stored in your local storage normalized?

Comment: Pack it up in some json blob, post it, demangle in NodeJs and INSERT/UPDATE into the database.